# java browser using mozilla webclient

Tags: java, webclient, mozilla

I have downloaded the xulrunner.zip and webclient_2_0_a9_rc3.zip .
Can some one explain me through a simple code of JAVA so that mozilla webclient will call any web page.
I want to call a we page in a jframe.A simple demo that implement calling of web page in jframe using mozilla web client.

Please help.I just need to know how to implement this thing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [getting started guide](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/blackwood/webclient/ref_guides/Developer_guide/getting_started.htm), with the [sample java code here](http://lxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/java/webclient/classes_spec/org/mozilla/webclient/test/EMWindow.java) and [here](http://lxr.mozilla.org/mozilla/source/java/webclient/classes_spec/org/mozilla/webclient/test/EmbeddedMozilla.java)

Comment: i have tried this ,but it is to complex to run .Please help me with a simple code that implement web client in a jframe and call a web page at runtime.